# Create a Terminal Menu GUI in C

Tags: c, gui

I found this very cool Python menu that will display a GUI menu in the terminal. Is this possible to do in c? I've compile a little hello world in `gtk+ 2.0`, but it looks like it will only run in X11.

[Python Menu](https://gist.github.com/abishur/2482046)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use the [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) menu library (http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/menus.html). Which is actually what that python code uses to generate the menu.

But making the menu in C will be more work and look exactly the same as the Python version. So unless you have a good reason to use C I would suggest sticking with Python.

Answer (score 2):

You could alternatively use this library called [Termbox](https://github.com/nsf/termbox).